# I need to accept underscore character "_" in regex email validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to accept the `_` character before the `@` character in an email validation regex.  I did not write this code, and I am having some difficulties understanding and modifying it.

Example:

> myemail_@gmail.com

```js
 function($){
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
    };
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function(){
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {

...

 "email": {
                    // Shamelessly lifted from Scott Gonzalez via the Bassistance Validation plugin http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                    "regex": /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
                    "alertText": "* Correo inválido"
                },
              
...
            
            };
            
        }
    };
    $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: [Email addresses are notoriously hard to validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). Your best solution is not to use a regex, but add server-side code to send a confirmation email to the address.

Comment: So is it required to have an `_`, or only if there is an `_` that it is before the `@`?

Comment: If you're just trying to make sure there isn't an `_` after the `@`, might be able to get away with this: `@[^_]+$`.

Comment: @Blazemonger : Maybe OP don't want / or can't access server-side. This is a JS question, and regex seems to be the best approch

Comment: @dustmouse is optional accept character _ before @,

Comment: @Blazemonger i need validate this field in the client side

Comment: I see [this regex accepts the underscore before `@`](https://regex101.com/r/rY6hD3/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this sentence, thank you anyway:

```js
"regex": /(^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[._-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)_@([0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[._-][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/i,
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the @ sign didn't you? simply add the underscore before it.

```
 "regex": /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))[_@]((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
```

Comment: Second, i'll test it... btw add []

Comment: Yeap that one works for me, sorry about the error :(

Answer (score 0):

\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}\b to validate email